# Perl: How do I sort each index of an array containing strings of numbers

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, foreach

I have an array reading numeric values from a text file. Each index of the array contains a string of numbers separated by a space and in random order. How do I sort each index of numbers in numeric order from lowest to highest? This is what I have so far:

```
print "\n\nNow sorted: \n";
foreach $line(@lines)
{   
chomp($line);
@nums = sort(split (//, $line));
print "$nums"."\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you show the sample input file content?

Comment: Aside from `"$nums"` where I think you want `join(' ', @nums)`, what do you think is wrong with your current code?  And as @Guru said, can you share some input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines = <DATA>;

foreach my $line (@lines) {
    my @nums = sort { $a <=> $b } split ' ', $line;
    print "@nums\n";
}

__DATA__
7 2 9 6 4 10
3 6 8 8 10 1
9 4 10 9 2 5
5 0 2 3 7 8
```

Output:

```
2 4 6 7 9 10
1 3 6 8 8 10
2 4 5 9 9 10
0 2 3 5 7 8
```

Note that the above modifies your script just a little.  Remember to always `use strict; use warnings;`  Note also the anonymous sub `{ $a <=> $b }` after `sort`.  This is needed to `sort` numerically.  Without it, a string comparison would have been done, and the first `print`ed line would be `10 2 4 6 7 9`.  It also appears that you were attempting to `split` on a zero-width match, i.e., `split //, $line`.  The result of this `split` is a list of single characters which comprised the line--not what you wanted, as you needed to `split` on spaces.  Lastly, you populated `@nums` and then `print`ed `$nums`.

Comment: if you are just feeding a line to `split ' '`, no need to chomp it - trailing whitespace will be ignored

Comment: @ChristopherFevrier: if it worked for you, click on the big checkmark to mark this as an accepted answer